# how can I show messagebox icon of my own choice or my own PNG in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, messagebox

I want to discuss about **Visual C++ MessageBox ICON**s | **AfxMessageBox**.
I'm using **Visual studio 2015**, and **visual c++ mfc based** projects. I want to show my own PNG image or Other icon in place of MB_ICONASTERICKS, MB_ICONWARNING, MB_ICONINFORMATION, etc. Waiting for answer!

Comment: A `MessageBox` provides a fixed set of icons. If you need a dialog with a custom icon, you cannot use `MessageBox`. You'll have to implement your own.

Comment: Please can you tell me what can i do? what to do? & HOw to do? (waiting)

Comment: Implement a dialog, either through the resource editor, manual editing of a resource script, or through code. If you need a step-by-step guide, Stack Overflow is the wrong place. If you have a **specific** programming problem, you can ask that. As it stands, this question is too broad for the Q&A format.

Comment: :/ than please can you tell me which is the right place for that?

Answer (score 1):

The MessageBox function provides stock standard options, and you have the ability to choose between a specific set of buttons, and a specific set of icons.

If your application's behaviour deviates from this norm, you'll have to write your own code to do that. Here's an excellent article that demonstrates the technique in detail: [XMessageBox - CodeProject.com](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1239/XMessageBox-A-reverse-engineered-MessageBox). You should be able to use it out of the box for your needs.

Comment: That's essentially a link-only answer. Consider making it a comment instead.

Comment: I consider my answer as the first sentence - which indicates that this cannot be done using the raw APIs. The link is there to guide the OP towards an alternative course of action.

Comment: @Mudassar As others and I have pointed out, it cannot be "solved" the way you're expecting to. I've provided a link to an article that does something like what you want.

Comment: @Vada Poche, there was a mistake with me. I tried later and it just worked :) Thank You! :)